# rundeck build with gradle failes

Tags: gradle, rundeck

I would like to build an run rundeck locali to test some changes.
Use a devcontainer because of the horrably old java version.

Build failes with

> Execution failed for task ':grails-webhooks:processResources'.
>
> > Could not copy file '/workspaces/rundeck/grails-webhooks/grails-app/conf/application.yml'
> > to
> > '/workspaces/rundeck/grails-webhooks/build/resources/main/application.yml'.
> > Could not set file mode 777 on '/workspaces/rundeck/grails-webhooks/build/resources/main/application.yml'.

Last time I wrote Java is 10+ year and I never used Gradle before.
No idea where to look, no seach for chmod or 777 or looking in the build.gradle helped me finding the problem.

environement described here: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/muehan/rundeck/blob/main/.devcontainer/Dockerfile)